# Unable to get value from file

Tags: bash

I try to get the value of "length" of the first line of different text files but I am getting this error :

```
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Here is the first line of one file :

```
><some info>  <some info>  | <other info> | <otherinfo> [Source:xxxx/xxxx;xxxx:xxxx] | <some info> | length=2812
```

So I want to get the value 2812. After many tests, the best I can get is this :

```
    for file in ./*.txt
    do
      LLINE=$(head -n 1 "$file" | awk -F "length=" '{print $NF}')
      echo "${LLINE}."
      if [[ "${LLINE}" -le 1500 ]];
      then
        <some code>
      else
        <some code>
      fi
    done
```

My output is :

```
2812
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
376
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
...
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: Where's the period in your output? Try `echo "[$LLINE]"`

Comment: Can you show us an extract from the file?

Comment: Maybe the first line in the text files are not in the same structure?

Comment: `(error token is "` Your file has DOS line endings. Remove them, and it should be fine.

Comment: If you’re performing numerical comparisons use arithmetic operators `(( ... ))`, instead of the double brackets.

Comment: Try running `dos2unix` over the input file, this will remove any DOS line endings like @KamilCuk mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

maybe grep would be better for LLINE?

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found with all your help !
This was DOS line endings error since those files were generated by someone using windows.

I just added a sed command to get rid of this :

```
LLINE=$(head -n 1 "$file" | awk -F "length=" '{print $NF}' | sed $'s/\r//')
```

Comment: You could replace all that with `LLINE=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS="=";RS="\r\n"}{print $NF;exit}' "$file")`